# Using webpack with js_bundling and rails 7

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-7, jsbundling-rails

I'm currently building an application using new rails 7 and [js_bundling](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/main/README.md) gem with webpack (not webpacker). But I'm having trouble making the javascript work.

I am currently packing all my sources into `assets/builds/application.js` with webpack which is working properly, and then including them in `assets/config/manifest.js` the following way:

```js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../builds
```

And finally i use `javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` in my `views/layouts/application.html.erb` to include it. I don't see where the includes are really coming from and no includes that I tried actually worked.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on what to change. I'm fairly new to this concept of bundling so an explanation of how rails uses these includes would be welcome as well.

Comment: Can you see that your assets were created when you run webpack config?